# How to properly create a particular R.id in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I'm trying to learn Android / Android Studio. I'm working on an app that is basically a very simple web browser set to start at google.com.

The project can't find the symbol variable webview and I'm not sure how to properly create it.

```
package obfuscated.obfuscated;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String URL = "http://www.google.com";

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl(URL);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The particular problem line is `webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);`

How can I create this resource properly? I understand that R is generated so I am curious how to do that in Android Studio.

I don't know if it matters, but the above `onCreate` method is taken from a previously working Eclipse project.

Comment: you should start with a basic Android tutorial before asking questions on this site. Android is based on XML-Layout-files which define your UI. There you define the IDs. As this is really the fundamental basics of Android, you should learn it first.

Comment: My problem with that is finding the exact general android development tutorial that fixes my specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create this resource properly?

There should be a `<WebView>` element in your layout (presumably located in `res/layout/activity_web_view`) whose `android:id` value is `@+id/webview`.

> I understand that R is generated so I am curious how to do that in Android Studio.

The same way that you would in Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, NetBeans, AIDE, or a plain text editor -- have a widget in your layout with the specified ID.

Comment: Thank you - Specifically, I added the line `<item android:id="@+id/webview"/>` to the end of activity_web_view to fix the problem.

Comment: Correction - my previous comment creates an error, "Didn't find class "android.view.item" on path". `android:id="@+id/webview"` was all that was needed.